# How to serve SVG icons using Interpolation in Angular 7 from a JSON file?

Tags: json, angular, svg

To display content in the Angular 7 components, we are using JSON. I have come to an issue with using the SVG icons from our UX team when serving them to the component via JSON. I know that using the img tag it will not allow me to use a CSS class to change the icons color and will require multiples of the same icon and is not ideal for this project. I have tried multiple ways to get this to work. I have tried embedding the svg string via

```
"icon": "data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path fill="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z"/><path d="M9 16.2L4.8 12l-1.4 1.4L9 19 21 7l-1.4-1.4L9 16.2z"/></svg>",

<embed [src]="items.icon">
```

but I get the error "Unexpected token h in JSON at position 64"

I also tried using interpolation within the SVG tag, but I get a similar error as above.

I have also tried interpolation within a div tag, but I get the path instead of an icon.

What I need to be able to do-
1. Place SVGs in JSON and serve it to the component via interpolation.
2. Change the class on the SVG to change colors and opacity

Is there any documentation for using SVGs in Angular 7 components via interpolation from JSON?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the data you have you should use src on a img tag.

```
<img [src]="item.icon">
```

It is even better if you could use it as HTML tag.

```
"icon": "<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path fill="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z"/><path d="M9 16.2L4.8 12l-1.4 1.4L9 19 21 7l-1.4-1.4L9 16.2z"/></svg>",

<div [innerHTML]="items.icon"></div>
```